# Entry options in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Following the guidelines in the biblatex [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) p. 68, I am adding `useauthor`, `useditor`, and `usetranslator` to the `options` field of an entry in my `.bib` file:

```
@book{sweet1871,
    AUTHOR = "{Pope Gregory I}",
    TITLE = "King {A}lfred's {W}est-{S}axon version of {G}regory's {P}astoral {C}are",
    YEAR = "1871",

    EDITOR = "Henry Sweet",
    LANGUAGE = "Old English",
    LOCATION = "London",
    NUMBER = "45",
    OPTIONS = "useauthor = false, useeditor = true, usetranslator = false",
    ORIGLANGUAGE = "Latin",
    PAGETOTAL = "xlii + 509",
    PUBLISHER = "N. Tr{\char"00FC}bner",
    SERIES = "{E}arly {E}nglish {T}ext {S}ociety",
    SUBTITLE = "With an {E}nglish translation, the {L}atin text, and an introduction",
    TRANSLATOR = "{King Alfred}"
}
```

My `.tex` file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, onecolumn, oneside, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode,xltxtra} % XeLaTeX
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping = tex-text} % support TeX conventions like ``--''
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant = american]{english}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{csquotes} % for language-specific quotation marks
\usepackage[style = numeric, sorting = none, language = american, abbreviate = true, backend = biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ReferencesBiblatex.bib} % my catalog of references

\begin{document}

\cite{sweet1871}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The output, however, does not come out right:

[image]

Not only are my specifications in the `options` field ignored, but it's also not rendering the information about the original language correctly.

Here is my console output warnings:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Ignoring undefined option 'useauthor '
(biblatex)                at entry 'sweet1871'.

Package biblatex Warning: Ignoring undefined option 'useeditor '
(biblatex)                at entry 'sweet1871'.

Package biblatex Warning: Ignoring undefined option 'usetranslator '
(biblatex)                at entry 'sweet1871'.

Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'fromLatin' undefined
(biblatex)                at entry 'sweet1871' on input line 158.
```

My question is - what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks as if biber doesn't like the spaces after the options. Write them as `useauthor=false,`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You were right, that fixed it. The `Bibliography string 'fromLatin' undefined` problem is still there, though.

Comment: Try `ORIGLANGUAGE = "latin",`

Comment: @HåkonMalmedal: That fixed it!

Comment: This space issue will be fixed in biber 1.2.

Comment: Actually, it's fixed in biber 1.1

Comment: Library catalogs list Gregory I as the author of this book, cf. e.g. Library of Congress and Harvard's Hollis. You suggest that Alfred should be in the translator field, but he _is_ already there. I see what you mean by having sorted under "Pope" and "King" - I should remove the curly braces. I don't know what the field ``sortauthor`` is - the ``biblatex`` documentation makes no mention of it.

Comment: @jon: I see your point, but putting King Alfred first implies that _he_ wrote a book called 'King Alfred's West-Saxon version of Gregory's Pastoral Care', doesn't it? The title is of course Henry Sweet's. Since I work in this field, I should add that I would always look for 'Sweet' in the bibliography to find an entry such as this.

Comment: @jon: If we both prefer to list such an entry under the editor, then what is the disagreement?

Comment: I don't agree that this question is too localized. It identifies a more general problem, that ``biber`` doesn't accept spaces in the entries for ``useauthor``, ``useeditor``, and ``usetranslator``. This could be considered a bug, and the authors of ``biber`` responded and decided to fix it. I'm voting for reopening the question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's fixed in biber 1.1